# Packaging python bottle app as a single application

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bottle

I have developed a python application using bottle (in Linux) and have been trying to package it as a single file using the following:-

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'static:static' --add-data 'views:views' myapplication.py --onefile --noconsole
```

Pyinstaller did not show any errors but when I launch the application, I got an error in the web browser saying the template is not found.

The application works fine without packaging.

Can someone point me to the right direction?  Thank you.

=================================

Additional info:

In my bottle code, I have the following:-

```
@route('/' + TEMP_DIR + '/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./' + TEMP_DIR)

@route('/css/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/css')

@route('/js/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/js')

@route('/img/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/img')

@route('/')
def home():
    info = {'application_name': APPLICATION_NAME, 'version': VERSION}
    return template('main_page.tpl', info)
```

Sample of code in html:-

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
```

Directory structure:-

```
myapp.py
   +
   +----static
   |      +-----css/<css files>
   |      +-----js/<js files>
   |      +-----img/<img files>
   |
   +----views
          +-----<tpl files>
```

BTW if I put the static and views directories into the folder containing the compiled binary file, the application works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, we'll need to see a portion of your code and the exact error (traceback) that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by going through the PyInstaller and Bottle documents in detail.  This is how I did it:-

I added the following (sample only) in the bottle app as PyInstaller unpack the files into the tmp directory.  The code tells bottle where to locate the unpacked files.

```
BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR = ''

try:

if getattr(sys, 'frozen') and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR = sys._MEIPASS
    #Modify template
    bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0,BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR + '/views')

except:

BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR= '' 

@route('/css/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    if (BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR != ''):
        return static_file(filename, root= BUNDLE_TEMP_DIR + '/static/css')
    else:
        return static_file(filename, root='./static/css')
```

Then I run PyInstaller using this (my directory structure is as above):

python3 -m PyInstaller --name busker-helper --add-data 'static/css/*:static/css' --add-data 'static/js/*:static/js' --add-data 'static/css/*:static/css' --add-data 'views/*:views' busker-helper.py --onefile --noconsole

The above runs under linux.  In Windows, replace ":" (colon) with ";" (semi-colon).

You may also need to include the --hidden-import option in PyInstaller.

Hope the above helps someone.